# Detecting superfluous #includes in C/C++

Tags: c++, c, refactoring, include, dependencies

I often find that the headers section of a file gets larger and larger all the time, but it never gets smaller. Throughout the life of a source file, classes may have moved and been refactored and it's very possible that there are quite a few `#include`s that don't need to be there and anymore. Leaving them there only prolong the compile time and adds unnecessary compilation dependencies. Trying to figure out which are still needed can be quite tedious.

Is there some kind of tool that can detect superfluous `#include` directives and suggest which ones I can safely remove?
Does lint do this maybe?

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/74326/how-should-i-detect-unnecessary-include-files-in-a-large-c-project

Comment: The linked question only seem to address the issue on Windows, using Visual Studio in particular.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

It's not automatic, but [Doxygen](http://www.doxygen.nl/) will produce dependency diagrams for `#included` files. You will have to go through them visually, but they can be very useful for getting a picture of what is using what.

Comment: This is a great way to see chains.. seeing A -> B -> C -> D and A -> D immediately reveals the redundancy.

Comment: @Tom: That is a horrible Idea: For one It doesn't show if those includes are needed or not and second, the list of includes should not depend on indirect includes that may change in the future (Redundant includes are usually not such a big problem anyway, thanks to include guards and compiler magic), but on which classes / functions are actually used in the file (Your compiler shouldn't have to go through thousands of lines of template code that don't even get instantiated)

Comment: @albert, can you include screenshots of this, and briefly describe where to click in the doxygen output?

Comment: @GabrielStaples It is not my answer, so I don't want to add information to it. I only corrected the link (as the hosting place it referred to stopped / seized to be used).

Comment: @GabrielStaples (or anyone else still wanting to know this): see the `INCLUDE_GRAPH` option in the [configuration](https://www.doxygen.nl/manual/config.html#config_dot)

Comment: Just to clarify the "have to go through them" part: there is one generated per file, so for a large project there will be very many to search through.

Answer (score 201):

Google's cppclean (links to: [download](https://github.com/myint/cppclean), [documentation](https://code.google.com/p/cppclean/)) can find several categories of C++ problems, and it can now find superfluous #includes.

There's also a Clang-based tool, [include-what-you-use](https://github.com/include-what-you-use/include-what-you-use), that can do this. include-what-you-use can even suggest forward declarations (so you don't have to #include so much) and optionally clean up your #includes for you.

Current versions of [Eclipse CDT](http://www.eclipse.org/cdt/) also have this functionality built in: going under the Source menu and clicking Organize Includes will alphabetize your #include's, add any headers that Eclipse thinks you're using without directly including them, and comments out any headers that it doesn't think you need.  This feature isn't 100% reliable, however.

Comment: It does now.  I just starting using it.  See my note here.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1301850/tools-to-find-included-headers-which-are-unused/7111685#7111685

Comment: The cppclean repository is down, you can now get it here: https://bitbucket.org/robertmassaioli/cppclean/ (the original site is still useful for some example usage though)

Comment: I updated the link to a maintained cppclean fork: https://github.com/myint/cppclean

Comment: include-what-you-use seems still in development, after a somewhat long hiatus there are news posted to the page (latest entry: 2014/11).

Comment: The project include-what-you-use is still active. 4 June 2015 include-what-you-use 0.4 was released.

Comment: Note that cppclean seem to find them only in header files, not cpp files, from the doc: "Unnecessary #includes in header files".

Comment: [Tools to find included headers which are unused?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1301850/995714)

Comment: Does Eclipse CDT use google's iwyu tool under the hood?

Comment: @wizurd - I haven't kept up with recent developments in Eclipse CDT, but I don't think so. iwyu is thorough and relatively slow. Eclipse CDT's analysis is fast (interactive) and, when I tested it, less accurate.

Comment: Latest `cppclean` *(0.13)* reports lots of unused includes for Konsole sources, yet
removing any results in compilation errors. `include-what-you-use` is a bit better in that regard: it also has lots of false-positives, but at least some of removed includes indeed weren't needed. Btw, worth noting that `include-what-you-use` is packaged for many GNU/Linux distros, so you don't need to install it from sources *(which isn't straightforward btw)*. The package can go under alternative name `iwyu`.

Comment: Woah, that Eclipse feature built in to it is pretty cool! I never knew that existed. I may add it to my [Eclipse doc](https://github.com/ElectricRCAircraftGuy/eRCaGuy_dotfiles/blob/master/eclipse/Eclipse%20setup%20instructions%20on%20a%20new%20Linux%20(or%20other%20OS)%20computer.pdf).

Comment: @JulianW The `deheader`-fork you linked isn't updated. The [original website](http://catb.org/~esr/deheader/) resp. https://gitlab.com/esr/deheader is still updated.

Comment: @Dominik thx, I deleted the comment.

Answer (score 77):

Also check out [include-what-you-use](https://github.com/include-what-you-use/include-what-you-use), which solves a similar problem.

Comment: IMHO this answer needs a lot more upvotes, as once the kinks are worked out Google's IWYU tool will be the definitive tool for this task.

Comment: sudo apt-get install iwyu

Comment: Seems great - with two cavaets 1) last update Feb 2106 2) Gogole themselves use it only for C++, not C, which the OP requested.

Comment: Can you explain a little bit how a user should use it ? The README isn't very clear about what contains the output of the python script.

Comment: I am using this, but it is not always 100% correct. Maybe 70% times it gives the correct suggestions.

Answer (score 30):

The problem with detecting superfluous includes is that it can't be just a type dependency checker.  A superfluous include is a file which provides nothing of value to the compilation **and** does not alter another item which other files depend on.  There are many ways a header file can alter a compile, say by defining a constant, redefining and/or deleting a used macro, adding a namespace which alters the lookup of a name some way down the line.  In order to detect items like the namespace you need much more than a preprocessor, you in fact almost need a full compiler.

Lint is more of a style checker and certainly won't have this full capability.

I think you'll find the only way to detect a superfluous include is to remove, compile and run suites.

Comment: None of this will be an issue if the include files are laid out well.  If you ever need to include file A before file B, you're doing it wrong (and I've worked on projects where they did it wrong).

Comment: @David, yes but that depends on the years of devs before you doing it correctly.  I can say with great certainty that the odds of that happening favor the house, not you :(

Comment: Yes, but I generally find out about that when modifying a program, and suddenly I've got a compilation error (if I'm lucky) or an obscure bug.  That seems to keep the #include files honest, at least in the long run.

Comment: I'd say the exact contrary. All you need is a type dependency checker. It might not compile after you've arranged includes accordingly, but these are problems that should be dealt with anyway.

Comment: @Benoit, then you would be ignoring a class of issues that compile but semantically change the meaning of your program.  Consider how a #define in one file can alter a #if branch in another.  Removing a header can still allow this to compile with different results

Comment: I could be wrong here (again - I should try it & post facts, not post on my best recollection...) but I'm pretty sure that PC-Lint / Flexelint will detect if a header influences/alters the compilation in any way.  Regular lint, not so sure...

Answer (score 14):

I thought that [PCLint](http://www.gimpel.com/html/pcl.htm) would do this, but it has been a few years since I've looked at it.  You might check it out.

I looked at [this blog](http://www.riverblade.co.uk/blog.php?archive=2008_09_01_archive.xml#3575027665614976318) and the author talked a bit about configuring PCLint to find unused includes.  It might be worth a look.

Comment: I use PCLint regularly and it does tell me of unused headers. I'm careful to comment out the header #include and re-compile to be sure that the header is truly unused...

Comment: too expensive. not a viable tool for the masses.

Answer (score 7):

The [CScout](http://www.spinellis.gr/cscout/) refactoring browser can detect superfluous include directives in C (unfortunately not C++) code.  You can find a description of how it works in [this](http://dx.doi.org/10.1002/smr.369) journal article.

Answer (score 6):

Sorry to (re-)post here, people often don't expand comments.

Check my comment to crashmstr, FlexeLint / PC-Lint will do this for you.  Informational message 766.  Section 11.8.1 of my manual (version 8.0) discusses this.

Also, **and this is important, keep iterating until the message goes away**.  In other words, after removing unused headers, re-run lint, more header files might have become "unneeded" once you remove some unneeded headers.  (That might sound silly, read it slowly & parse it, it makes sense.)

Comment: I know exactly what you mean, and my reaction was "Ewwww".  I hate code like that.

Answer (score 5):

I've never found a full-fledged tool that accomplishes what you're asking.  The closest thing I've used is [IncludeManager](http://www.profactor.co.uk/includemanager.php), which graphs your header inclusion tree so you can visually spot things like headers included in only one file and circular header inclusions.

Answer (score 4):

You can write a quick script that erases a single #include directive, compiles the projects, and logs the name in the #include and the file it was removed from in the case that no compilation errors occurred.

Let it run during the night, and the next day you will have a 100% correct list of include files you can remove.

Sometimes brute-force just works :-)

---

And sometimes it doesn't :-). Here's a bit of information from the comments:

1. Sometimes you can remove two header files separately, but not both together. A solution is to remove the header files during the run and not bring them back. This will find a list of files you can safely remove, although there might a solution with more files to remove which this algorithm won't find. (it's a greedy search over the space of include files to remove. It will only find a local maximum)
2. There may be subtle changes in behavior if you have some macros redefined differently depending on some #ifdefs. I think these are very rare cases, and the Unit Tests which are part of the build should catch these changes.

Comment: Be careful of this - say there are two header files which both include a definition of something. You can remove either, but not both. You'll need to be a bit more thorough in your brute force approach.

Comment: Maybe this is what you meant, but a script that removes a single include, and leaves the last removed include out if it was successfully removed would do the trick.

Comment: Bad idea. If a header file #defines a constant BLAH and another header file checks #ifdef BLAH, removing the first header file may still successfully compile but your behaviour has changed.

Comment: Didn't think about it too much, but you are correct. God is in the details, as they say.

I'm not sure leaving the .h file out at each step is sufficient - this is still a Greedy search (capitol G), which doesn't always find the optimal solution. It will give a CORRECT solution, unlike the original.

Comment: @Graeme - Hopefully the Unit-Tests, which are part of the build (hopefully) will catch such faults.

Comment: This also can cause problems with system headers, since different implementations might have different things included in #include <vector>.  Even if you stick to one compiler, the headers could change over different versions.

Comment: This won't find cases where you're including a header that includes the header that you really need.

Answer (score 4):

I've tried using [FlexeLint](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PC-Lint) (the Unix version of [PC-Lint](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PC-Lint)) and had somewhat mixed results.  This is likely because I'm working on a very large and knotty code base.  I recommend carefully examining each file that is reported as unused.

The main worry is false positives.  Multiple includes of the same header are reported as an unneeded header. This is bad since FlexeLint does not tell you what line the header is included on or where it was included before.

One of the ways automated tools can get this wrong:

In A.hpp:

```
class A {
  // ...
};
```

In B.hpp:

```
#include "A.hpp

class B {
    public:
        A foo;
};
```

In C.cpp:

```
#include "C.hpp"

#include "B.hpp"  // <-- Unneeded, but lint reports it as needed
#include "A.hpp"  // <-- Needed, but lint reports it as unneeded
```

If you blindly follow the messages from Flexelint you'll muck up your #include dependencies.  There are more pathological cases, but basically you're going to need to inspect the headers yourself for best results.

I highly recommend this article on [Physical Structure and C++](http://gamesfromwithin.com/?p=7) from the blog Games from within.  They recommend a comprehensive approach to cleaning up the #include mess:

> Guidelines
>
> Here’s a distilled set of guidelines from Lakos’ book that minimize the number of  physical dependencies between files. I’ve been using them for years and I’ve always been really happy with the results.
>
> 1. Every cpp file includes its own header file first. [snip]
> 2. A header file must include all the header files necessary to parse it. [snip]
> 3. A header file should have the bare minimum number of header files necessary to parse it. [snip]

Comment: Lakos's book is great for education -- aside from his outdated observations on compiler technology.

Answer (score 4):

If you are using Eclipse CDT you can try http://includator.com which is free for beta testers (at the time of this writing) and automatically removes superfluous #includes or adds missing ones. For those users who have FlexeLint or PC-Lint and are using Elicpse CDT, http://linticator.com might be an option (also free for beta test). While it uses Lint's analysis, it provides quick-fixes for automatically remove the superfluous #include statements.

Comment: The reason for that is that our bookkeeping department is not able to invoice lesser amounts. If you count the time you might save it is not that unreasonable. Once, we've got the ability to get credit card payments we can lower the price significantly. Another option would be a sponsor for our development efforts. Our financing model requires us to gain profits to finance our research work. I would be happy to sell licenses much cheaper, but can't. May be we will contribute it to CDT and you get it for free, but that I have to finance somehow. I forgot, you can try for free!

Comment: Re *"free for beta testers"*: Is that still relevant (not a rhetorical question)?

Comment: OK, the OP has [left the building](https://www.explainxkcd.com/wiki/index.php/979:_Wisdom_of_the_Ancients): *"Last seen more than 1 year ago"*

Answer (score 2):

[This article](http://gamesfromwithin.com/?p=7) explains a technique of #include removing by using the parsing of Doxygen. That's just a perl script, so it's quite easy to use.

Comment: The script finds some includes to remove but it gives also a lots of includes that cannot be removed. It seems that it doesn't support class enum, seems also that it has a bad time with macro and sometimes with namespace.

Answer (score 2):

[CLion](https://www.jetbrains.com/clion/), the C/C++ IDE from JetBrains, detects redundant includes out-of-the-box. These are grayed-out in the editor, but there are also functions to [optimise includes in the current file or whole project](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/clion/2016.3/optimizing-imports.html).

I've found that you pay for this functionality though; CLion takes a while to scan and analyse your project when first loaded.

Comment: No longer available in new clion :( Only showing as grayed-out that this include isn't used but there is no "action" to cleanup

Answer (score 2):

Here is a simple [brute force way of identifying superfluous header includes](https://cognitivewaves.wordpress.com/2017/04/14/header-file-dependencies/). It's not perfect but eliminates the "obvious" unnecessary includes. Getting rid of these goes a long way in cleaning up the code.

The [scripts](https://github.com/cognitivewaves/misc/tree/master/check-header-includes) can be accessed directly on GitHub.

Answer (score 1):

I once found a [WebKit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebKit) [Perl](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perl) script that did just what you wanted. It'll need some adapting I believe (I'm not well versed in Perl), but it should do the trick:

*[find-extra-includes](http://trac.webkit.org/browser/branches/old/safari-3-2-branch/WebKitTools/Scripts/find-extra-includes)* (in *webkit/branches/old/safari-3-2-branch/WebKitTools/Scripts*)

(This is an old branch because *trunk* doesn't have the file anymore.)

Answer (score 1):

There are two types of superfluous *#include* files:

1. A header file is actually not needed by
   the module (.c, .cpp) at all
2. A header file is needed by the module,
   but it is being included more than once, directly, or indirectly.

There are two ways in my experience that works well for detecting it:

1. `gcc -H or cl.exe /showincludes` (resolve problem 2)

   In the real world,
   you can export `CFLAGS=-H` before make,
   if all the Makefiles do not override
   CFLAGS options. Or as I used it, you
   can create a `cc`/`g++` wrapper to add `-H`
   options forcibly to each invoke of
   `$(CC)` and `$(CXX)`. And prepend the
   wrapper's directory to the `$PATH`
   variable. Then your make will all
   use your wrapper command instead. Of
   course, your wrapper should invoke the
   real GCC compiler.    This tricks
   need to change if your Makefile uses
   GCC directly. Instead of `$(CC)` or
   `$(CXX)` or by implied rules.

   You can also compile a single file by tweaking the command line. But if you want to clean headers for the whole project. You can capture all the output by:

   ```
   make clean

   make 2>&1 | tee result.txt
   ```
2. PC-Lint/FlexeLint (resolve problem,
   both 1 and 2)

   Make sure to add the +e766 options. This warning is about:

   > unused header files.

   ```
   pclint/flint  -vf   ...
   ```

   This will cause the `pclint` output to include header files, and nested header files will be indented appropriately.

Comment: Is "`/flint`" literal? Why isn't there a space before `/flint`?

Answer (score 1):

There is a free tool, [Include File Dependencies Watcher](http://www.mobile-mir.com/cpp/1007/), which can be integrated into Visual Studio. It shows superfluous #includes in red.

Answer (score 1):

`clangd` is doing that for you [now](https://github.com/clangd/clangd/issues/79). Possibly `clang-tidy` will soon be able to do that as well.

Answer (score -2):

To end this discussion: the C++ preprocessor is [Turing complete](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turing_completeness). It is a semantic property, whether an include is superfluous. Hence, it follows from [Rice's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rice%27s_theorem) that it is undecidable whether an include is superfluous or not. There can’t be a program that (always correctly) detects whether an include is superfluous.

Comment: Did I ask for an "always correct" solution? This answer is not very productive for the discussion.

Comment: Well there have been numerous posts discussing problems that such a program would have to deal with. My post gives a conclusive and correct answer to that part of the discussion.

And I for one would not like it, if a program told me, I could safely remove an #include and then my code doesn't compile anymore. (or worse - still compiles but does something differently). ANY such program bears this risk.

Comment: Between all the SPECULATION about how hard that would be and how you MIGHT solve one obstacle or another, I gave you the only 100% correct answer. I find it quite impudent to say that this wasn't productive...

Comment: @Algoman taking a page from compiler design, conservative heuristics mean never having to say sorry.

Comment: I remembered that Rice's theorem states "There can't be a program which always can check if a given program solve this superfluous-includes problem". There can be a few programs which solve the superfluous-includes problem.

Comment: If a program doesn't ALWAYS give you the correct answer, then it doesn't "SOLVE" the problem. They can only solve some non-semantic subsets of the problem.

Comment: personally I found @Algoman's input very helpful. makes me realize how hard this problem is.

Comment: this is false. The c++ preprocessor is __*not*__ Turing complete.
http://stackoverflow.com/a/7508513/2918853

Comment: Do you understand the reasoning behind that claim? Recursion-depth having an (arbitrarily chosen) limit contradicts turing completeness as much as finite RAM contradicts your PCs turing completeness.

Comment: The recursion depth is signigicant however: No real compiler can have actual infinite recursion depth, therefore it is not turing complete making the problem solvable for any existing computer with any existing compiler.

Comment: By that reasoning, the Halting Problem is solvable, because no real PC has actual infinite RAM. There is no technical necessity for a limit on the recursion depth. That is just a design-decision.

Comment: @Algoman but that means that it's solvable in practice, since the maximum recursion depth needed to compile said program is known. I.e. if the program already compiles, when it doesn't have infinite recursion, and then the include analysis can be run safely (since the complexity of getting the correct includes is not asymptotically higher than compiling the program).

Comment: @DanM. that's complete nonsense. One include may set some preprocessor macro (say only it's include guard) then the next include may do something completely different based on the presence of that macro. Say it now doesn't include stdio, but defines a function named printf, which wipes your harddrive. Still compiles. Totally safe to remove that first include.

Comment: Even if the preprocessor wasn't turing complete, you'd still have to GUARANTEE that the removal of the include absolutely doesn't change the semantic of ANY program that includes your file. Now we're talking about Turing-Degree 2 - that's even infinitely harder than the halting problem.

Comment: @Algoman and compiler somehow figures out what `printf` function to include during the compilation process, so it means that so can a hypothetical include analyzer. Also, there is no need to provide strong "GUARANTEE" that removal of some include won't affect anything down the line (if you have a lib). In fact, there can't be such guarantee because transitive includes is a thing and people often mistakenly rely on them. But in that case it's their bug, not yours. You just document which headers you include exactly and relying on everything else is UB (not part of the public interface).

Comment: Oh yes, there is a need to provide a strong guarantee. Just because you (falsely) believe this didn't affect YOUR use-case only shows how little your understanding of the problem is. You are talking with an expert on this topic here and you are suffering from the Dunning-Kruger effect.

Comment: @Algoman. Are you saying there's a source tree that a compiler can compile (obviously by reaching into all its includes). But there is no program/analyzer/dry-run-compiler that can identify which includes got reached into and which did not?