# Removing unused includes

Tags: c++

Are there any tools which parse .h files and recommend the removal of `#includes`. For example if the defines in the include are not being used or if it is possible to do a forward declaration instead.

I work on both windows and linux platforms.

Comment: possible duplicate of [C/C++: Detecting superfluous #includes?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/614794/c-c-detecting-superfluous-includes)

Comment: This isn't a 'tool' but.. generally you won't have too many includes - you could just do it manually! comment out, compile - if it fails keep it otherwise remove it and then repeat.

Comment: a good answer to a similar question can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/615057/7717505

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[include-what-you-use](http://code.google.com/p/include-what-you-use/) is intended to do this.

Answer (score 2):

[ReDHead](http://redhead.ifs.hsr.ch/) is a project for exactly that. It's an Eclipse plug-in.

Answer (score 2):

I was looking for such tool some time ago and I now found out that this functionality is also provided by [Resharper C++](https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper-cpp/) plugin for Visual Studio.