# How to exclude files for cppclean run?

Tags: python, c++

I am using `cppclean` ( as described here https://stackoverflow.com/a/615057/356726 ) to find unused `.h #include` s.

Unfortunately in crashes for some files. Can I exclude files from being processed? Just want to excluded the troublemakers.

So far I have only found a very stupid workaround by using `cppclean` on a bogus copied directory and manually remove them (gosh!).

Answer (score 1):

If you have the [find program](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/find.1.html) available, you can try something like

`find /path/to/source/directory -type f ! -name 'file1.name' ! -path '/file2/path' -exec /path/to/cppclean {} +`.