# Forward declaration tool

Tags: c++, c, forward-declaration

In order to reduce unnecessary coupling and decrease compilation time, is there a tool which can help locate (and perhaps interactively remove) unnecessary inclusion of header files in C/C++ translation units?

In particular, a tool that can detect, for every **translation unit**, all those types whose `#include` directives can be replaced with forward declarations, in the context of **that translation unit**.

If this is not achievable, do useful approximations exist?

Comment: Duplicate of this question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/614794/c-c-detecting-superfluous-includes  ?

Comment: `#include` is a *directive,* not a *macro.*

Comment: @Neil the question is not exaclty the same (that guy is asking for completely unused includes removal), but the most voted answer actually talks about forwards declarations also. So, thanks.

Comment: I suppose you want to _decrease_ the compile time. These kind of "optimisations" are useless, you wont get a significant decrease in compile time with tweaks like that.

Comment: @nyarlathotep108 why do yu think this will decrease compile time?

Comment: @MichaelWalz The translation units become exponentially bigger if there is no control over the #include directives, and so also the compilation time is affected by it.

Comment: @nyarlathotep108 you should clarify your question or ask another question with a more precise description of what exactly you want and why.

Comment: @MichaelWalz edited, hope it is more clear