# Use clangd to get instances of a specific warning in a big project and apply it's fix from the command-line

Tags: c++, clang, qt-creator, clang-tidy, clangd

I'm working on a big c++ project, using cmake/QtCreator.

The code has been around for a long time and so build times are slow.

I believe removing unused includes would reduce this build time significantly.

In my IDE (QtCreator), the most common warning relating to includes is the following :

`Included header something.h is not used directly (fix available)`

Calling the fix on all instances using the QtCreator's GUI would be painfully slow, which makes me wonder :

Is there a way to script this ?

1. call clangd on my `compile_commands.json`
2. ask it to only log the specific warning (`Diagnostics.UnusedIncludes`),
3. apply the suggested quick fix using clang-tidy

I tried to call clangd with my path to compile-commands as well as clang-tidy but it neither wrote the checks nor applied the fixes, simply telling me that I should not call clangd from the command-line :/
source for the warning name: https://clangd.llvm.org/config#unusedincludes

Comment: I can't think of a specific way to do this outside of some kind of shell script.  It actually shouldn't even be that hard since the quick fix for unused include just means deleting a line.   Not that this is a solution, but vim + coc + clangd could have knocked this out in less time than it took to type out this question =]

Comment: I'm asking for a way to do this using a shell script. I changed 'do' in the question to 'script' for it to be clearer. Have you done something similar ?

Comment: I have done similar things.  First, I would figure out how to run clangd from the command line.  Run it on a couple files, and figure out a nice way to parse the output.  I'm not sure how involved all that would be.  You'll get a decent response here if you get as far as you can, post what you tried, and add the `[bash]` or `[shell]` tags.  The guys on `[bash]` are pretty creative and helpful.  By the way, I'm assuming Linux here, but QT is cross platform, so if you are on Windows, you want to use the `[batch]` tag instead.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/614794/detecting-superfluous-includes-in-c-c https://github.com/include-what-you-use/include-what-you-use?tab=readme-ov-file#applying-fixes

Comment: Are you looking to automate application of multiple quick-fixes in a single file, or across multiple files in a directory/project? For the first one, I believe clangd 17 supports that out of the box (there is a ["fix all" code action](https://reviews.llvm.org/D147684)).