# Include File Ordering Strategy

Tags: c++, include, coding-style, header-files

I've seen fairly consistent advice that an implementation file (.cc / .cpp) should include its corresponding class [definition file *first*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014632/clean-up-your-include-statements), before including other header files.  But when the topic shifts to header files themselves, and the order of includes they contain, the advice seems to vary.

[Google coding standards](http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/cppguide.xml?showone=Names_and_Order_of_Includes#Names_and_Order_of_Includes) suggest:

1. dir2/foo2.h (preferred location — see details below).
2. C system files.
3. C++ system files.
4. Other libraries' .h files.
5. Your project's .h files.

It is unclear what the difference is between entry 1 and 5 above, and why one or the other location would be chosen.  That said, [another online guide](http://www.possibility.com/Cpp/CppCodingStandard.html) suggests this order (found in the "Class Layout" section of that doc):

1. system includes
2. project includes
3. local includes

Once again there is an ambiguity, this time between items 2 and 3.  What is the distinction?  Do those represent inter-project and intra-project includes?

But more to the point, it looks as if both proposed coding standards are suggesting "your" header files are included last.  Such advice, being backwards from what is recommended for include-ordering in implementation files, is not intuitive.  Would it not make sense to have "your" header files consistently listed first - ahead of system and 3rd party headers?

Comment: The difference between 1 & 5 is clarified by the "In dir/foo.cc, whose main purpose is to implement or test the stuff in dir2/foo2.h, order your includes as follows:" remark found right above the 1-5 listing.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Header file order](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4800991/header-file-order)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The order you list your includes shouldn't matter from a technical point of view.  If you designed it right, you should be able to put them in any order you want and it will still work.  For example, if your `foo.h` needs `<string>`, it should be included inside your `foo.h` so you don't have to remember that dependency everywhere you use `foo`.

That being said, if you *do* have order dependencies, most of the time putting your definition file last will fix it.  That's because `foo.h` depends on `<string>`, but not the other way around.

You might think that makes a good case for putting your definition file last, but it's actually quite the opposite.  If your coding standards require the definition first, your compiler is more likely to catch incorrect order dependencies when they are first written.

Comment: `If your coding standards require the definition first, your compiler is more likely to catch incorrect order dependencies when they are first written`.  Yes, that is a premise of my question.  Why then would the contrary seemingly be recommended in other guides?

Comment: @BrentArias: Simply because other guides' authors either haven't considered it or don't value this simple-but-oh-so-useful check.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not aware of any verbatim standard but as a general rule of thumb include as little headers as possible especially within other header files to reduce compile times, conflicts, and dependencies.  I'm a fan of using forward declaration of classes in header files and only including the header and definition on the .cpp side whenever I can afford to do so.

That said my personal preference is below:

For Headers:

1. C++ headers
2. 3rd party headers
3. other project headers
4. this project's headers

For Source:

1. precompiled header file
2. this source file's header
3. C++ headers
4. 3rd party headers
5. other project headers
6. this project's headers

Pointers or suggestions are usually to avoid conflicts and circular references, otherwise it's all personal preference or whatever policy you prefer adhere to for collaborative projects.

Comment: Theoretically, would it not help you to have "this/other project's headers" appear before C++ and 3rd party headers?  It would prevent accidental dependency hiding, yes?

Comment: yes this may be true except as stated in my opening paragraph i generally have very few if any headers included in any header file ...

Comment: @Brent: not if each header is already test in its own source anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding Google's style:

There is no ambiguity, at all.

The first header included should be the header related to `this` source file, thus in position 1. This way you make sure that it includes anything it needs and that there is no "hidden" dependency: if there is, it'll be exposed right away and prevent compilation.

The other headers are ordered from those you are the least likely to be able to change if an issue occurs to those you are the more likely to. An issue could be either an identifier clash, a macro leaking, etc...

By definition the C and C++ systems headers are very rarely altered, simply because there's so many people using them, thus they come second.

3rd party code can be changed, but it's generally cumbersome and takes time, thus they come third.

The "project includes" refer to project-wide includes, generally home-brawn libraries (middle-ware) that are used by several projects. They can be changed, but this would impact the other projects as well, they come fourth.

And finally the "local includes", that is those files who are specific to this project and can be changed without affecting anyone else. In case of issue, those are prime candidates, they come last.

Note that you can in fact have many more layers (especially in a software shop), the key idea is to order the dependencies starting from the bottom layer (system libs) to the top layer.

Within a given layer, I tend to organize them by alphabetical order, because it's easier to check them.

Answer (score 0):

For Headers:
this project's headers
other project headers
3rd party headers
C++ headers

For Source:
this source file's header
this project's headers
other project headers
3rd party headers
C++ headers

This orders minimize the chance to MISS some required header inside .hpp file. Also it minimize INTERSECTIONS of 3rd party headers etc. And all hpp modules compiles with minimum required dependensis.

for example:
->test.hpp

```
// missing #include <string> header
void test(std::string& s);
```

->test.cpp

```
#include <string> 
#include "test.hpp"
// we hide bug with missing required header
```

->test2.cpp

```
#include "test.hpp"
#include <string> 
// compilation error with missing header
```