error: no match for 'operator<<' (operand types are 'QTextStream' and 'const char [3]')
This is a piece of Qt-based code that is a year old and that I probably have compiled in all sorts of contexts and many, many times, and every time unbeknownst to me. It is in a file called DPolygon.cpp where it seems we are defining DPolygons (no idea what this is even) :
QTextStream& operator<<(QTextStream& stream, const DPolygon& polygon)
{
    std::for_each(polygon.constBegin(), polygon.constEnd(),
                  [&stream](const QPointF& pnt) { stream << "( "<< pnt.x() << ", " << pnt.y() << " ) "; } );

    return stream;
}

Today I (newly) get this error :
error: no match for 'operator<<' (operand types are 'QTextStream' and 'const char [3]')
  236 |                   [&stream](const QPointF& pnt) { stream << "( "<< pnt.x() << ", " << pnt.y() << " ) "; } );
      |                                                   ~~~~~~ ^~ ~~~~
      |                                                   |         |
      |                                                   |         const char [3]
      |                                                   QTextStream

In qtextstream.h in the declaration of QTextStream I can see :
     QTextStream &operator<<(const char *c);

I know arrays and pointers aren't exactly the same thing, but this was working until today ! What could have changed or happened ? What other info could I give that would help ?
This actually first appeared when I clicked "rebuild".
We are using Qt 5.12.11 and Qt Creator 12.0.1 and CMake at least 3.19 and MinGW 7.3.0. None of this has changed recently in a way that would meaningfully be related.

The error means that the left operand is QTextStream and the right operand is const char[3] but the compiler can't find operator<< that takes operands of those two types. In your example, you've overloaded operator<< for operands of type QTextStream and DPolygon.

You've definitely #include'd QTextStream?

I mean, it's not me. But worth looking at.

QTextStream has an operator<<(const char*) which should be getting called here.

this was working until today !

The most likely cause is that the file where your operator<< is defined doesn't #include <QTextStream> on its own, but relies on getting it from somewhere else.
This is sometimes called "leaky headers" and may lead to code being broken by a Qt update, or by other seemingly unrelated includes being changed.
QTextStream is likely still forward-declared somewhere, but operator<< needs the include.
You should always include what you use to prevent these issues, and tools such as include-what-you-use can help with that.

I totally agree, I thought we were following this (and this part of the code is always so clean). But indeed in this case QTextStream is only declared at the top of the file instead of included ! Why ? Maybe some black magic ...

@Charles maybe someone did this to speed up compilation. It's not uncommon to forward-declare things to avoid additional dependencies. In hindsight, it wasn't that good of an idea, but you know, hindsight is 20/20.

Oh really it speeds up compilation ? Because including i.e. text-copying & parsing that extra code is longer ? Compilation time saves us development time (we keep compiling & testing & changing & recompiling & retesting) so this could be the reason. But then why isn't it done for everything ? I see other includes that could possibly be gotten rid of this way. Or was maybe an analysis performed to figure out which includes are redundant in context, and which ones aren't ? Is that easy, or can it be done automatically ?

You probably want to look at https://stackoverflow.com/q/373142/5740428 and https://stackoverflow.com/q/1869439/5740428. I'm not aware of any tools that would benchmark the cost of individual headers, only of whole translation units. This is getting really off-topic for this Q&A though.
