# What is the tool to check include file that are useless?(c++)

Tags: c++, linux, eclipse, eclipse-cdt

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Tools to find included headers which are unused?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1301850/tools-to-find-included-headers-which-are-unused)

I would like to check useless header file in c++ files(.h and .cpp)

During developing, There are so many relations between files.

So it cause compile time more longer.

Can you tell me what's the tool that help me.

Thank you.

Comment: When i looked for such a tool, i did not found one :(

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1301850/tools-to-find-included-headers-which-are-unused

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [Dehydra](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Dehydra).

From the website:

> Dehydra is a lightweight, scriptable, general purpose static analysis tool capable of application-specific analyses of C++ code. In the simplest sense, Dehydra can be thought of as a semantic grep tool.

It should be possible to come up with a script that checks for unused #include files.

Answer (score -1):

I use [lint](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908799/xcu/lint.html), Verify the link, it does mention unused variables, unreachable statements and many more.