# C/C++: Removing unnecessary includes

Tags: c++, c, header-files

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [C/C++: Detecting superfluous #includes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/614794/c-c-detecting-superfluous-includes)
>   [How should I detect unnecessary  #include files in a large C++ project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74326/how-should-i-detect-unnecessary-include-files-in-a-large-c-project)

I'm looking to do some house cleaning in our code base. I would like to start by removing all unnecessary header includes from our source files (*.c and *.cpp). Does anyone know of a tool or technique for doing this?

We are using GCC on Mac, Linux and Solaris. Using Visual Studio on Windows. I looked through the documentation of both compilers and there did not seem to be a option to make it warn for unnecessary includes.

Any thoughts or advice are appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I had to do this once and I ended up doing this:

1. I removed almost every `#include` statements from both my haeder and source files
2. I tried to compile my source code
3. Whenever the compiler complains about something undefined, I either:

   - Added a minimal declaration instead of a header inclusion wherever I could (something like: "class SomeClass;" instead of `#include "someclass.hpp")
   - Added the required include when I had no other choice.
4. Go to 2. until it succeeds.

I admit this is long and boring, but it worthed it.

Comment: The problem with that is there are over 5000 source files and a total of 22 projects. Because there is a lot of common code between the various projects I would have to rebuild each project each time I need to test changes. At that point it's not even about the man hours, it's about waiting 1.5 hours to compile them all and try again.

I fear this is what's going to end up happening, but I was hoping for an easier, automated solution.