# How should I detect bottleneck of compile time in a large C++ project?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, compiler-optimization

I want to reduce compile time of a large C++ project.
I tried to use precompiled headers, interface and etc.
But before I move on, I want to know whether any tool which helps detect why compile time is so long.
Somebody suggests pc-lint and I will give a shot.
[How should I detect unnecessary #include files in a large C++ project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74326/how-should-i-detect-unnecessary-include-files-in-a-large-c-project)
But if there are other tools which analysis compile time and talk about any hints to increase compile speed, let me know.
Thanks in advance.

Environment : Microsoft Visual Studio C++ 2008 or 2010.

Comment: Not directly an answer, but you did turn parallel build on?

Comment: General comment is don't include headers you don't need. The worst thing for build time is a header file called includes.hpp that includes all the possible header files you need. I've seen that bloat re-compile time.

Comment: How about a hardware upgrade?

Comment: Make sure you have a proper build system which only rebuilds those files that have changed. Then you can use things like PIMPL to minimize the amount of coupling and compilation dependencies.

Comment: @David: I'm doing that all the time ... each header equipped with a '#ifndef foo \n #define foo ... #endif' of course. Should I not?

Comment: @steffen So I could be wrong on this so I would be happy to be proven wrong my understanding is lets say I have a file obj.c which include inc.h which includes h1.h and h2.h. If I change something in h2.h and I only need h1.h in obj.c that means obj.c still needs to be rebuilt since the timestamp on h2.h has been touched and inc.h has a dep on h2.h and obj.c has a dep on inc.h... Than again I could be wrong... But from my experience I changed a project from this method and compile time speed up a TON...

Comment: @steffen: we are not talking about guarding your headers (which is mandatory), we are talking about avoiding the `#include` directive as much as possible in headers, because it creates dependencies and rebuild-from-hell.

Comment: Ask does the program need to be this complex? Every time I speed up a build, someone just increases the complexity of the program until it takes exactly the same time as it did before.

Comment: @steffen Just use `#pragma once`. The compilers understand it well.

Answer (score 5):

one approach i like is to review the preprocessor output of a few of your sources -- just read some of it from the compiler's perspective rather than the somewhat abstracted representation that is `#inclu`sion. chances are you will find some large chunks of includes/libraries you don't need and weren't necessarily aware of the existence (or need) of the dependency/include. from there, decide which dependencies can be removed. even if your dependencies were all correct, large outputs can also suggest how you might approach *dividing* larger modules into smaller pieces.

Answer (score 4):

C++ *not* being modular (yet), compilation bottlenecks are often due to include issues; that is using including too many files when they are not needed. It is also possible that those includes are needed *at the moment*, but could become superfluous with some simple reengineering.

- to detect superfluous includes, you can check [include-what-you-use](http://code.google.com/p/include-what-you-use/), the only issue you'll have is that it works on top of Clang, so you'll need some setup there.
- otherwise, you need to review your code, and specifically the *headers*.

Since the tool is self-sufficient and documented, let me expand a bit on the review process.

1. Any header that has more than a couple `#include` is highly suspicious.
2. On the contrary, if you have a source file chock-full of various types and functions and it only has a couple includes, it probably means that one of the headers brings too much.

If you have trouble knowing what is required, what is not, and how to remove superfluous headers, I recommend a reading of [Pimpls - Beauty Marks You Can Depend On](http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill04.htm); if you do not know what a Pimpl is, read [Compilation Firewalls](http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/024.htm). I would advise cautiousness though, Pimpl has a runtime and maintenance cost, so only use it when it really is necessary. Personally I would absolutely recommend it in the public headers of a library you deliver to 3rd party (ABI compatibility), and otherwise try to avoid it.

If manual inspection is not your forte, you can generate the preprocessor output for each **header** (do not worry about source files too much), and check the bigger outputs.

Answer (score 3):

I am not aware of any tool for betterment of the compile time, but few manual remedies, I can suggest (consider this as comment):

1. Have `#include` guards with every header file, so that multiple
   inclusions won't make any issues
2. Reduce member function body, inline function body putting directly
   into the header files; just have their declarations
3. Check if there are no unnecessary `template` function and classes;
   remember that tempaltes become `inline` by default. Too much of
   templates/metaprogramming cause huge compilation time.
4. If number of `#define`s are unnecessarily high then they would
   increase preprocessing stage, which ultimately increases the
   compilation time

Answer (score 2):

You could look into [unity builds.](http://buffered.io/posts/the-magic-of-unity-builds/)
Basically it's including all `.cpp` files into one .cpp file and only compiling that one file.
I've tested it on a big project and it was really effective.
It works because of it uses much less I/O when it includes all your headers/cpp's once and not for every cpp.

Now we don't use unity builds anymore because we all got a SSD hardware upgrade, and they are just awesome.

Here's a related SO question about Unity builds: [#include all .cpp files into a single compilation unit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/543697/include-all-cpp-files-into-a-single-compilation-unit)

Comment: +1 - very interesting comment on Unity Builds - I will have to try that the next time I touch a low-level header.  As for SSDs, I'm late to the game: just added it to a laptop after a HDD crash - the speed increase suggested that I should change the compile box to SSD.  After your comment, I will definitely make the change, once capacity is a bit higher/price a bit cheaper.