# Can I identifying unused C++ header by looking at the symbols in the binary?

Tags: c++, header, linker, nm

Can I identify unused C++ headers by looking at the symbols in the binary?

My end goal is to remove accidentally/unnecessary included C++ headers. Through some search, I realized there is no up-to-date, free, Linux tools available for this.

[Detecting superfluous #includes in C/C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/614794/)

[How should I detect unnecessary #include files in a large C++ project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74326/)

I am wondering whether it is possible to achieve this at a higher level, by looking at symbols. Scheme showing below:

[image]

`mycomponent.cc` includes `component_1.hh` and `component_2.hh`, and suppose `component_2.hh` is the unused include, and they are dynamically linked.

Here is the plan: Suppose I know all of the libraries I need to link to in the first place. If I get all the **undefined symbols** from `mycomponent.so`, say `my_list`, and compare it with all the **defined symbols** in `component_1.so` and `component_2.so`. If `component_2.so` contains no symbol from `my_list`. Then I would know that `component_2.so` is not needed, then I can go back to see what headers are from `component_2` that shall be removed. Of course, this would only work if all the headers from `component_2` are not used in `my_component`

Is this viable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer - no.  Whatever symbols are not actually used by code will get optimized away and not be in the final binary.  And even if they weren't, there is no way to determine *from the binary* which header include(s) the sumbols originally came from.

What you are looking for is a source code analyzer, that will parse your source code and point out any issues with it, such as unused/unnecessary header includes.